# PHP add/remove values from array created by json

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this after using `json_decode()` on a response from a Json webservice:

```
    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 80B37803-6278-5351-BC7A-D3A2FBFF8AA7
            [1] => test
            [2] => 
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70B37803-6278-5351-BC7A-D3A2FBFF8AA8
            [1] => test 2
            [2] => 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 90B37803-6278-5351-BC7A-D3A2FBFF8AA9
            [1] => test 3
            [2] => 
        )
```

To print the array I use the following code:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($responseArticle); echo '</pre>';
```

How can I edit this kind of array in order, for example, to add a 3rd row or delete one of the already exsisting row?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far. It might give us a better idea of what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: But basically the answer is exactly the same way you would for any other PHP array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = json_decode($json_data);
```

add inner data 
 adding a column for 11 number of row

```
$newArray[11][4] = 'this is the 4th column';
```

for delete

```
unset($newArray[11][4]);
```

for adding row

```
$newArray[lastindex] = array('90B37803-6278-5351-BC7A-D3A2FBFF8AA9','test4','');
```

for delete row

```
  unset($newArray[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

to add another value of an array is to use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) and to delete it you can use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php). See the example below.

```
<?php 
        $json_array[11] = array('80B37803-6278-5351-BC7A-D3A2FBFF8AA7','test','');
        $json_array[12] = array('70B37803-6278-5351-BC7A-D3A2FBFF8AA8','test 2','');
        $json_array[13] = array('90B37803-6278-5351-BC7A-D3A2FBFF8AA9','test 3','');

        array_push($json_array, array('90B37803-6278-5351-BC7A-D3A2FBFF8AA9','test 4',''));
        echo '<pre>';print_r($json_array);echo '</pre>';

        unset($json_array[14]);
        echo '<pre>';print_r($json_array);echo '</pre>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add in some info for N key:

```
$responseArticle[N] = array('80B37803-6278-5351-BC7A-D3A2FBFF8AA7', 'testN', '');
```

To delete info stored in N key:

```
if(isset($responseArticle[N]) {
 unset($responseArticle[N]);
}
```

Here N can be any number, say 3 as you have asked in the question.